# Custom Vue components inside editable Tabulator table cells

Tags: vue.js, tabulator, quasar-framework

Looking for some help with Tabulator (https://tabulator.info/).
I'm trying to use vue components (from Quasar) inside Tabulator cells to edit table data, but can't get it right.

I'm creating my components instance as described in this article: https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/, then listen to events from said components and update table cell data by calling Tabulators own `success()` method (or `cancel()` to cancel editing).

```
Tabulator.prototype.extendModule('edit', 'editors', {
  customEditor(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams) {
    const colType = cell.getField()
    const ComponentClass = Vue.extend(
      self.compList.find(item => item.type.includes(colType)).comp
    )
    const cellValue = cell.getValue()

    self.tableInputInstance = new ComponentClass({
      propsData: {
        value: cellValue,
        indicator: false,
        autofocus: true,
        ...self.compList.find(item => item.type.includes(colType)).props
      }
    }).$mount()

    self.tableInputInstance.$on('input', e => onChange(e, 'input'))
    self.tableInputInstance.$on('change', e => onChange(e, 'change'))
    self.tableInputInstance.$on('blur', e => onChange(e, 'blur'))

    function onChange(e, evtType) {
      if (e !== cellValue) {
        success(e)
      } else {
        cancel()
      }
    }
    return self.tableInputInstance.$el
  }
})
```

Right now one of the issues I'm facing is that if I'm currently editing a cell and `success()` isn't called, I can't click another cell to make it editable / render my input component, only each second clicked cell turns editable.

[image]
What I want to have is a behavior exactly like in Tabulator demo here: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/edit#edit just with my own Vue input components. 
I've put up a demo app with my current setup here: https://codesandbox.io/s/tabulator-w-custom-inputs-4lr7k?file=/src/pages/Index.vue
Will greatly appreciate any ideas on how to fix this!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are trying to use Vue Components after Vue has parsed the DOM.

Vue will look for component tags when the DOM is first loaded, Instantiate each of the components and convert their tags into actual HTML from inside the components definition.

This only happens when the page is loaded, so when you are using a formatter and passing in a component you are just passing in standard HTML and that component tag isnt valid, therefore non of its functionality is triggered.

As far as i am aware there is no way to instantiate a component in that way after the page has loaded *(i would very much love it if someone could prove me wrong on this)*

Therefore any formatter that you want to set would need to use vanilla JavaScript, not a Vue component

Comment: You can mount the component to the already rendered DOM in mounted hook. The same way the Vue App does it.

Comment: Could you provide more details on this, there is no mounted hook in this instance as the table is rendered after the component it is used in has been mounted.

Comment: The idea is to use Tabulatory formatter method. Which can return HTML. So when you pass function that creates a div `document.createElement('div')` and you `set` an unique `id` to it, then you can call `new Vue({ render: YourComponent}).mount(yourId)`. It is overcomplicated but I got it working.

Answer (score -1):

Para renderizar un componente en quasar realize lo siguiente,
Archivo TabulatorTemplate.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler";
import { Quasar } from "quasar";

export function renderComp(comp, props) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");

  const app = createApp(comp, props);
  app.use(Quasar, {
    plugins: {}, // import Quasar plugins and add here
  });

  return app.mount(div).$el;
}
```

componente.

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from "vue";

const props = defineProps(["cell", "select"]);

onMounted(() => {
  console.log("props", props.cell);
});

function returnData() {
  return props.select(props.cell.value);
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <q-btn
      color="primary"
      icon="check"
      label="OK"
      @click="returnData"
      size="sm"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped></style>
```

dentro del archivo

```
import { renderComp } from "src/utils/TabulatorTemplate";
import BtnTabulatorComp from "src/components/Tabla/BtnTabulatorComp.vue";

const columns = [{
    title: "Eliminar",
    field: "age",
    hozAlign: "center",
    formatter({ _cell }) {
      return renderComp(BtnTabulatorComp, {
        cell: _cell,
        select: (val) => _select(val),
      });
    },
    frozen: true,
  },
];

function _select(val) {
    console.log("Selectect props", val);
   }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsAWo.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).